# Target Machine keeps dropping connectivity when i run arpspoof against it

Tags: arp, spoofing

first and foremost, I am new to all of this so any support or help would be appreciated.

- I have a target machine, (friend's iphone 8, approved for testing purposes) - xxx.xxx.0.12
- My Oracle VM Kali Linux Machine (configured for bridged adapter (eth0))
- I know my gateway address xxx.xxx.0.1

Whenever I try an arp poison, when i try to log into the web application on the iphone, it gets stuck at the loading screen, doesn't progress, and then ultimately drops connectivity.
I use the following code on 3 different terminals, in the following order:
`echo > 1 /procs/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` 
`arpspoof -i eth0 -t xxx.xxx.0.12 -r xxx.xxx.0.1`
`arpspoof -i eth0 -t xxx.xxx.0.1 -r xxx.xxx.0.12`

Additionally, I've tried playing around with ettercap, the same result happens. When i try to log into the web application on the iphone, it gets stuck at the loading screen and the ultimately drops connectivity.

Been looking all over for an answer but can't really find anything that's been concrete and helped. Any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Additionally, this website does require a viewstate generator. I don't know if that is relevant at all for arpspoofing, but i had to use it when i was doing a hydra BF. Idk if there is coding for that in this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be spooky if this worked.

Try

```
echo 1 > /procs/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

instead of

```
echo > 1 /procs/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Also run

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

while spoofing is in progress.
This way you can check/see the traffic going trough your Kali machine.